# HiveQL: HAVING clause for same dataset shows discrepancies for equivalent Oracle DB 11g querying

Tags: hadoop, oracle11g, group-by, hiveql, having

For a class project, I have to import a dataset into Oracle DB and a Hadoop cluster and use HiveQL to compare it with SQL.

I have to run queries on the data and estimate the run time for comparison of performances.

Data Table: 
One of the table is called RATINGS, which has MOVIE_ID, USER_ID and RATING fields which tabulates user ratings for some 500 movies.

MOVIE_ID and USER_ID are NUMBER fields and RATING is a FLOAT type field.

I am trying to run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT MOVIE_ID, AVG(RATING) FROM RATINGS GROUP BY MOVIE_ID HAVING AVG(RATING) > 3.5
```

Querying on Oracle returns 153 rows, whereas HiveQL on Hive returns 139 rows.

When I run:

```
SELECT MOVIE_ID, AVG(RATING) FROM RATINGS GROUP BY MOVIE_ID
```

Both platforms return same number of rows. Same data is imported on both platforms.

I have tried this variation, based on my internet search:

```
SELECT AV.MOVIE_ID, AV.AVRT FROM (SELECT MOVIE_ID, AVG(RATING) AVRT FROM RATINGS GROUP BY MOVIE_ID HAVING AVG(RATING) > 3.5) AV;
```

I ended up with same results.

Is there any restrictions on using HAVING clause in HiveQL? How is HiveQL different to the traditional RDBMS when it comes to aggregations?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the data? What movie IDs have different averages? Why are those averages different? Can you calculate an average where it's different and see which database you agree with? Is the difference something like 3.499999999999999999999 vs. 3.5 and therefore completely explainable via floating point arithmetic?

Comment: Thanks for that. To your point, I tried running Round(AVG(RATING)) > 3.5. There is a change in number of rows that is returned. But there is still difference between the two.

Comment: What is more surprising and equally confusing is that
SELECT MOVIE_ID, COUNT(RATING) FROM RATINGS GROUP BY MOVIE_ID HAVING Count(RATING) > 15;
returns same rows in both places.

Comment: I don't think that's a surprise. The number of rows (assuming you put the same data in there) would be the same what appears to be different is how the data is interpreted by the engine. You need to actually view the data and see what the problem is. I doubt more adding more functions will solve the issue without doing this.

Comment: Is there anyway to see how the engine is interpreting data? I am new to Hive and I don't know if there is any Oracle Explain Plan equivalent in Hive or any other way to dig into this.